# Android camera2 abandoned surface on Nougat but works on Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-7.0-nougat

**EDIT 05/05/2018**
I still do not know the reason why this happens, but apparently it does not affect Lolipop and Marshmallow devices. This error only comes up on Nougat 7.0 as far as I have tested.

---

I'm making a app that lets you record a video which then used for further processing. However, I'm currently having trouble with the recording part.

Code to setup/start the recording:

```
private void startRecord()
{
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(totalRotation);

    try
    {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        Surface recordSurface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
                    {
                        recordCaptureSession = session;
                        try
                        {
                            recordCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
                        }
                        catch (CameraAccessException e) {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {}
                }, null);
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx) {} // mediaRecorder.prepare()
    catch (CameraAccessException caEx) {} // cameraDevice.createCaptureSession()
}
```

Specifically at `cameraDevice.createCaptureSession()` method,
the problem lies in `recordSurface` being abandoned and thus throwing `IllegalArgumentException` on that line.

I have read some posts about this problem and most said that it was due to the variable going out of scope which caused the GC to kick in and delete the surface.

I've tried making it a member variable like the posts suggested but the error still persists. Others using the above resolution seems to fix the problem but it does not work on mine.

Any insight on this? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer? I have the same problem and I can't seem to fix it :(

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, this app at the time of developing was not required to support nougat, so I ultimately just went with the code above.

Comment: I have same problem as well. Tried changing compileSdk & targetSdk from 27 to 23 (Android Studio) but can't avoid errors (eg android endX not found). Did you find a good way to do it?